# Real touch inputs

Tags: pi-4, touchscreen

I'm developing a touch first website which I plan to display on a raspberry pi using a touchscreen.

When I tested the website on the pi (raspberry pi os) using a waveshare touchscreen, the website didn't work as expected.

Raspbian or the preinstalled chromium seems to translate the touch inputs into mouse inputs.

The website works flawless on other touch devices like phones and tablets.

Does raspbian (or the underlying debian) even support real touch inputs? Or is this an issue with chromium?

The touchscreen mentioned: https://www.waveshare.com/wiki/5.5inch_HDMI_AMOLED

Comment: Before asking, have you done any research and what about links to the refereed OS and hardware, and I would recommend to read the "How to ask" before posting, https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Bit baffled as the sites I've worked on and used assume a single point touch is a mouse press and long touch is the secondary press. Does the waveshare device support multi-touch or just emulate a mouse? The RPT device states * Touchscreen drivers with support for 10-finger touch and an on-screen keyboard will be integrated into the latest Raspberry Pi OS* so I would look to the Waveshare drivers first.

Comment: I've added a link to the touchscreen's documentation. Some gestures like pinch to to work, so the device should be capable of real touch inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently it was a chromium issue. Disabling overscroll navigation and starting chromium with the `--touch-event=enabled` argument, fixes my issue.